# Am I getting DDoSed, and what should I about it?

Tags: linux, debian, ddos

At the moment my server is lagging pretty bad, and it crashes.
It's a dedicated server which has run completely fine last two days.

What does this command do?

```
netstat -n|grep :80|cut -c 45-|cut -f 1 -d ':'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|more
```

This I what I get:

```
    154 76.217.x.xx
     11 79.51.xx.xxx
     10 174.119.xx.xx
      9 201.230.xxx.xxx
      8 24.184.xx.xxx
      8 127.0.0.1
      6 50.51.xxx.xxx
      6 216.121.xxx.xxx
      4 80.203.xx.xxx
      4 24.186.xxx.xxx
      4 223.25.xx.xxx
      4 119.93.xx.xx
```

What does the number beside the IP mean?
Does it mean connections? If so... the top IP is ddosing me?

Comment: There are 228 connections this doesn't look like a [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack let alone a DDoS attack. What is your I/O, CPU, memory, webserver, applictaion doing ?

Comment: Yeah, that was me. Sorry.   But seriously 228 connections is nothing. You have an issue on your web server.

Comment: @Jacob - you're a bad, bad man. Haven't you learned your lesson from that 500 connection DoS against Google?

Comment: may want to also check 443(?) connections for https as well, as its also a web port.

Comment: Are you sure your site didn't get listed on digg/slashdot/reddit/....

Comment: @Zoredache that'd be a pretty pathetic slashdotting if that's his full list of remote IPs asking for web pages, no?

Answer (score 14):

- `netstat` print network connections
- `-n` show numerical address
- `grep :80` filter connections connect to port 80
- `cut -c 45-` get only 4th and 5th column
- `cut -d: -f1` take the first field separate by colon
- `sort | uniq -c` sort by IP address and count the numbers of unique
  IP
- `sort -rn` reverse the numerical sort

You can use `awk` instead of `cut -c 45-` to get the 5th column only:

```
netstat -n | grep :80 | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
```

About your result, it seems normal, no DDoS. Take a look at `access_log` for more details.

Comment: +1, although <pedant> `sort -rn` is a reversed *numerical* sort` </pedant>

Comment: More pedantry: `cut -c 45-` grabs from the 45th character to the end of the line.

Answer (score 12):

Quanta & DTest explained what the command does.  Everyone will tell you that a few hundred connections does not a DoS make (talk to me when you have at least 5-10 *thousand*), and I'll expand on that by saying that in order for it to be a ***D***Dos you'd be seeing a lot more entries (probably with a lot more connections each) than what you're showing above.

---

When you have a problem with a server **DO NOT** jump to the exotic causes (DDoS, Cosmic Rays, Z0MG H4X0R3D!, etc.) -- Chances are you have a far more boring and mundane problem.

You say "it crashes" -- do you mean the whole server locks up, panics or otherwise requires a hard reboot?
If so, check your RAM ([MemTest86+ or similar](http://www.memtest.org/%29)).  That's usually the issue.

If it's not a real, hard crash start looking at the normal mundane troubleshooting items:

- Run `top`

  - What is the load average? What is it when you have a problem?
  - How much swap are you using? Are you using more when you have a problem? (If so, memory leak!)
  - What programs are trying to get on the CPU?
- Run your operating system's disk I/O information tools  (Not a Debian guy, maybe someone can list 'em?)

  - Are you disk bound? (is the disk constantly using 100% of its bandwidth?)
- Look at your network statistics

  - Are you hitting a bandwidth cap from your ISP?
- Look at your ancillary programs, if applicable

  - Database Connections
  - Shared File Systems
  - Any other resource that may be locked/blocking when you need it

Comment: +1: except in cases of being hacked with vast numbers of cosmic rays, this is solid advice.

Comment: @voretaq7 Thanks for the guide.

I found this in the error log: [Fri Aug 05 05:31:58 2011] [error] [client 91.194.219.139] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)

Answer (score 2):

The number is the number of unique entries for each ip (generated by `uniq -c`)

`netstat -n` will give you all the current network traffic, which you then pipe to `grep :80`, which only grabs connections on your web server. Next we cut out the leading part of the line with `cut -c 45-`, and then everything after the IP (starting at the colon) with `cut -f 1 -d ':'` then we sort it, get the unique IPs with a count (`uniq -c`) and then sort it in reverse order so the most IPs appear at the top.

This doesn't necessarily mean you are getting DDoS'd because the majority of traffic is coming from a single IP. Someone might be crawling your site for content or some other reason.

Comment: unique entries as?

Comment: @Muazam Number of 'active connections' at the time the 'netstat -n' command was run.